# Yii2 ArrayHelper::map left join select

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

I have users, orders and plans. When client buy plan, data is save in `orders` , plans are in `account_plan` and the information for user is in table `users`. In table `orders` is when the plan start and when it is expired. I use for Select2 ArrayHelper, but do not show the column 
here is a query

```
 $masAcc[0] = Yii::t('app', 'Choose plan');
 $masAcc['----------------'] = 
ArrayHelper::map(
\backend\models\Orders::find()
->select('orders.*,account_planLang.name as name')
->leftJoin('orders_props','`orders_props`.`order_id`= `orders`.`id`')
->leftJoin('account_plan','`orders_props`.`product_id`=`account_plan`.`id`')
->leftJoin('account_planLang','account_plan.id=account_planLang.plan_id')
->where('`orders`.`dt_end`<CURDATE() + INTERVAL 5 DAY AND `orders`.`dt_end`<CURDATE()')
->all(), 'id', 'name');
```

but the error is :
`Getting unknown property: backend\models\Orders::name`
here is Select2:

```
 $form->field($model, 'account')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                        'model' => $model,
                        'theme' => 'bootstrap',
                        'options' => [
                            'placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'app.choose'),
                            'class' => 'form-control select2'
                        ],
                        'data' => $masAcc,
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                            'allowClear' => true,
                        ],
                    ]);
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is no need to use **ArrayHepler::map()**. Try this way:

```
Orders::find()
  ->select('account_planLang.name as name, table_name.id as id')
  ->leftJoin('orders_props','`orders_props`.`order_id`= `orders`.`id`')
  ->leftJoin('account_plan','`orders_props`.`product_id`=`account_plan`.`id`')
  ->leftJoin('account_planLang','account_plan.id=account_planLang.plan_id')
  ->where('`orders`.`dt_end`<CURDATE() + INTERVAL 5 DAY AND `orders`.`dt_end`<CURDATE()')
  ->indexBy('id')
  ->column();
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because your query returns list of `Orders` models, which does not have `name` column, so it cannot represent result of this query. You need to use [`asArray()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequeryinterface#asArray()-detail) when you want to query field that is not available in model:

```
ArrayHelper::map(
    \backend\models\Orders::find()
        ->select('orders.*,account_planLang.name as name')
        ->leftJoin('orders_props','`orders_props`.`order_id`= `orders`.`id`')
        ->leftJoin('account_plan','`orders_props`.`product_id`=`account_plan`.`id`')
        ->leftJoin('account_planLang','account_plan.id=account_planLang.plan_id')
        ->where('`orders`.`dt_end`<CURDATE() + INTERVAL 5 DAY AND `orders`.`dt_end`<CURDATE()')
        ->asArray() // <- this
        ->all(), 
    'id', 
    'name'
);
```

Or add `name` field to your model:

```
class Orders extends ActiveRecord {

    public $name;

    // ...

}
```

Comment: I think user need to fetch `account_planLang.name`

Comment: he is using  alias `account_planLang.name as name` for the field. @SudharshanNair